# How to create an Excel chart of a subsection of a table that updates itself?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, spreadsheet

I'm working with a table that has a Day column followed by many others with different data. It looks like this:

[image]

I created a chart of this table, works fine and it updates itself if I add new values to the table.

But now if I create a chart only, let's say, of 2017 (the first values start in 2014) I get the chart but when I add values to the table it doesn't update and I have to do it manually.

What can I do to make it update automatically?

EDIT:

I tried with a pivot table as suggested by Máté, but the chart does not update after I add new rows to the table, just if values already in range change.

Answer (score 0):

To make it update automatically:

- convert your data to table (insert - table)
- insert a pivot chart (insert - chart - pivot chart) on the whole table

  - you can filter on pivot chart like you do in a pivot table
- after update of the data table you need to refresh source data of the chart (analyze - refresh), but this is still easier then selecting the data manually

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The data is already a table, that's why the complete chart updates correctly. I'm aware of pivot tables but, if possible, I would like to avoid having more than 1 table.

Comment: I don't understand your concern, what do you mean by "avoid having more than 1 table", you'll have only one table. Creating a pivot chart creates a pivot table, but you don't need to show it, just place your chart over it.

Comment: I'm not concerned, I just like to keep things simple if I can. Anyway, as I say in my edit of the question I tried  what you said and it's not working, the chart doesn't update. I think it may have to do with using a mac because  Excel still doesn't have Pivot Charts